# add class in jquery to a <li> without id

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have the following html:

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-header">head</li>
          <li><a href="index.html"><i class="icon-cog"></i> index</a></li>
          <li><a href="contacts.html"><i class="icon-globe"></i> contacts</a></li>
....
```

i'd like to put the `class='active'` in one of the `<li>` but with jquery.
i know that i've to use something like this:

```
function select() {
    $("li").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Which `li` do you want to add the class to?

Comment: How are you determining which `li` should be `active`, in response to what event, or criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('.nav-list li:eq(1)').addClass('active');
```

The number passed should be zero based, so that the second `li` is accessed by using `:eq(1)`.

---

For better performance, you should split up the selector, and use the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function:

```
$('.nav-list').children().eq(1).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

When you click an `li` remove class `active` from all `li`, than add class `active` to the clicked `li`.